# Query to update table blocked by another seemingly unrelated query to update another table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, blocking

We have a scenario where a long running query is updating a table is blocking a query attempting an update to update a completely different table. I see plenty of examples of how to find blocking queries, but in this case I do not see anything that helps me understand why an update to tableA would be blocking an update to tableB.

How can I begin to understand blocking like this?

Comment: Are there any foreign key relationships common between the two tables (totally a stab in the dark here)? Or, are there any triggers that might cause behavior against one table on update of the other?

Comment: no foreign keys on tableB, one foreign key on tableA